# java.sql.SQLException: Failed to parse bundle deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, repository, jackrabbit, jcr

I am trying to create JCR Repository. I am using Tomcat 7 and jdk 6 and jars as:

```
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
concurrent-1.3.4.jar
jackrabbit-api-2.5.2.jar
jackrabbit-core-2.5.2.jar
jackrabbit-jcr-commons-2.5.2.jar
jackrabbit-spi-2.5.2.jar
jackrabbit-spi-commons-2.5.2.jar
jcr-2.0.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
lucene-core-4.0.0.jar
postgresql-8.2-504.jdbc4.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.0.2.jar
```

My Context.xml file of Server:

```
<Resource 
            name="jcr/repository" 
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.jcr.Repository"
            factory="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepositoryFactory"
            configFilePath="C:/comrep/fiplrepository/repository.xml"
            repHomeDir="C:/comrep/fiplrepository/repository"></Resource>
```

My Servlet Class:

```
1)...InitialContext inc = new InitialContext();
2)...Context context = (Context) inc.lookup("java:comp/env");
3)...Object repository = context.lookup("jcr/repository");//This line gives error...
```

Line 3) gives an error as:

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException: failed to read bundle (stacktrace on DEBUG log level): deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to parse bundle deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.InternalVersionManagerImpl.<init>(InternalVersionManagerImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createVersionManager(RepositoryImpl.java:492)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:311)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:589)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepository.createRepository(BindableRepository.java:141)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepository.init(BindableRepository.java:117)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepository.<init>(BindableRepository.java:106)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepositoryFactory.getObjectInstance(BindableRepositoryFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at com.willcode4beer.demo.jcr.JcrDemoServlet.doPost(JcrDemoServlet.java:33)
    at com.willcode4beer.demo.jcr.JcrDemoServlet.doGet(JcrDemoServlet.java:22)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException: failed to read bundle (stacktrace on DEBUG log level): deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to parse bundle deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.loadBundle(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:902)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.getBundleCacheMiss(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:766)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.getBundle(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:749)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.exists(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:560)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.InternalVersionManagerImpl.<init>(InternalVersionManagerImpl.java:162)
```

and My repository.xml file contain:

```
<Repository>
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository" />
    </FileSystem><!-- security configuration -->
    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
        <AccessManager
            class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleAccessManager">
        </AccessManager>
        <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleLoginModule">             
            <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous" />
        </LoginModule>
    </Security>
    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces"
        defaultWorkspace="default" />
    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
        <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://myPort/DMS"/>
          <param name="user" value="postgres" />
          <param name="password" value="pass" />
          <param name="schema" value="postgresql"/>
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="pm_ws_${wsp.name}_"/>
    </FileSystem>
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager">
          <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://myPort/DMS"/>
          <param name="user" value="postgres" />
          <param name="password" value="pass" />
          <param name="schema" value="postgresql"/>
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="pm_ws_${wsp.name}_"/>
           <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
        <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index" />
        </SearchIndex>
    </Workspace><!-- Configures the versioning -->
    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
        </FileSystem>
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager">
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://myPort/DMS"/>
          <param name="user" value="postgres" />
          <param name="password" value="pass" />
          <param name="schema" value="postgresql"/>
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="pm_vs_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>       
    </Versioning>
    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index" />
    </SearchIndex>
</Repository>
```

In my Repository path I can see that repository folder is generated and also in my database named tables are created. So what going wrong here and what do I change here that program will run.
Also how can I configure for RMI for that my other application can invoke this repository?
Please help me, I stuck here from last week.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: What is the question here ? Please be specific.

Comment: @AndrewAnderson the question is whats wrong with my code that throwing ItemStateException as given above and if it solve then second is how to configure that code with RMI? that's it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "failed to read bundle: deadbeef-face-babe..." message is a symptom of a repository inconsistency.  You might find these articles from the Adobe CQ5 knowledge base to be helpful: [Fix the "jcr:system" node](http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/Crx/Troubleshooting/FixTheJcrSystemNode.html) and [Consistency Check](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/upgrading/consistency-check.html).

Comment: thks for answer but I am not using crx, I am using Tomcat 7 with jcr 2.5 and i think in tomcat there is no console.sh/bat file hence unable to find nodeType as well as to delete it. how can rectify this problem with my current configuration?

Comment: thanks, it works. I just changed my SearchIndex as suggested by above links in my repository.xml. but now I am getting another error like: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.JackrabbitAnalyzer overrides final method tokenStream.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream; will you please help me whats going wrong with here...?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the lucene core version ?
It seems to me that Jackrabbit 2.5.2 is for Lucene 3.6 not 4.0 thus this might be the cause of your new error.